# Bootstrap Responsive Grid layout: can't show rows of 3 div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, grid

I'm using Bootstrap 3 responsive grid, and I have an issue with my layout.

Here is the HTML structure I have today:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

This is working fine for "mobile" (col-xs-6) and "desktop" (cold-md-3) but on "tablet" (col-sm-4), it looks like this (`*` being a div):

```
* * *
*
* * *
*
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Bootstrap utilizes a 12 column grid but you're trying to incorporate 16 columns into your layout. This is why you're  seeing the fourth column pushed under the first three col-sm-4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to utilize Bootstrap's [column wrapping](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping) feature..

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/TrLJF1qIlC

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Read more about [the Bootstrap grid](http://blog.codeply.com/2016/04/06/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works/) and column wrapping.

Comment: Great, it's working nicelly, in fact my mistake was to put .row divs everyhere... Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You should use col-sm-3 instead of col-sm-4

Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/6bzf4ze7/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```